# Render Artifacts from Proximity

Tags: rendering, geometry-nodes

I'm working on a project where everything is looking fine in the viewport, yet under certain circumstances there are weird artifacts in the render. The render looks fine if there is more space between certain edges, but if the edges are closer together these artifacts show up. The proximity is being generated through geometry nodes. I need the edges as close as possible for my project, and that's where I get these artifacts. Here are examples:

Wireframe of the edges close together. To me, the topology looks good.
[image]

Here's how it looks in the viewport with cycles:
[image]

Here is how that renders in cycles:
[image]

Here is an eevee render:
[image]
When I increase the distance between the outer and inner edges the render looks fine. Here is a wireframe example:
[image]
And here is how that renders in cycles:
[image]
Now there are no artifacts. It renders equally well in eevee. If it would help I could upload the Blender file, but for now I am going with these pictures. I can't figure out what is causing these issues with the renders when the outer edges are close, and as I mentioned before, I need the edges to be as close together as possible!

Answer (score 0):

Eureka! I solved it!! :-)

It turns out that having a subdivision surface modifier in the stack of your reference object messes up the render for the geometry node object. Once the subdivision surface modifier is removed, the artifacts are removed!

My project uses "reference" objects that I modeled and dragged into a geometry node project. Here is an example:
[image]

Note that the object itself has a subdivision surface modifier with zero levels and that is turned off in the viewer. Here is the render that resulted:
[image]
Once the subdivision surface model is totally removed from the stack,
[image]
The render turns out great!
[image]
Problem solved!